# Using CreateInstance in Windows 10 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-desktop

The following code doesn't compile in a Windows 10 Universal App, but does in a .Net console app (both using Reflection):

```
string objType = "MyObjType";
var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var newObj = a.CreateInstance(objType);
```

It would appear that universal windows apps don't contain the method `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`; nor do the Assembly objects seem to contain `CreateInstance`.

Activator.CreateInstance has 16 overloads in .Net and only 3 in A Win 10 app.  I'm referencing the desktop extensions.

Is this type of construct still possible in Windows 10 and, if so, how?  What I'm trying to do is to create an instance of a class from a string representing that class.

Comment: Sounds like you want to get the type, e.g. with `Assembly.GetType(...)` and then call `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`. Which assembly is the type in?

Comment: The type is in the current assembly (why I was trying to call GetExecutingAssembly), so I could certainly do that if I could get the executing assembly.

Comment: Well can't you use `typeof(Foo).Assembly` where `Foo` is the type you're writing the code in?

Comment: Thanks, Jon - while this, in itself, doesn't work, you pointed me in the right direction.  Basically, the key command is Type.GetType() which does accept a string and return a type.  I presume this is a security measure to make sure you can only reflect your own assembly.

Comment: See my ansewr - I believe you can still reflect over other assemblies, but reflection has moved somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection in CoreCLR / Windows 10 etc has moved quite a lot of what used to be in `Type` into [`TypeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo). You can use [`IntrospectionExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo) to get the `TypeInfo` for a `Type`. So for example:

```
using System.Reflection;
...

var asm = typeof(Foo).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var type = asm.GetType(typeName);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Hopefully all of that is available to you (the docs can be a little confusing, in my experience). Or you could just use:

```
var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

... with either an assembly-qualified type name, or the name of a type in the currently-executing assembly or mscorlib.