# System.InvalidCastExecption error message when a programm with Interop.photoshop.dll after updating Windows10

Tags: c#, windows-10, photoshop

After updating to Windows 10, C# program on VisualStudio 2017, which processes images and uses Interop.Photoshop.dll and Interop.PhotoshopTypeLibrary.dll, got following issue :

```
"System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Photoshop.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Photoshop._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{5DE90358-4D0B-4FA1-BA3E-C91BBA863F32}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Photoshop.ApplicationClass.Quit()"
```

The same program was working before the update and it works on windows 7 and 8.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why does this was at -1?  Why someone downvoted this?  This a legit question!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it running Photoshop as administrator and then restart my machine.
Besides that I used the following function to find my instance of PS.

And instead of crashing again, it got executed correctly:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Find the Photoshop instance and return it
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Photoshop Application COM object</returns>
    [STAThread]
    public static Photoshop.Application SetPhotoshop()
    {
        Type photoshopType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Photoshop.Application");
        Photoshop.Application psApp = null;
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(photoshopType);
        if (photoshopType != null)
        {
            try
            {
                psApp = (Photoshop.Application)obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
        return psApp;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must close Visual Studio and start it by right clicking and choosing "Run as administrator"

Answer (score -2):

Anyways, what I have found out is that it's not a Photoshop problem, it's a .Net Problem:

[Using CreateInstance in Windows 10 Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494138/using-createinstance-in-windows-10-universal-apps)

This answer suggests a solution, though I haven't tried it out yet:

[InvalidCastException of a Activator.CreateInstance object during an installation procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116694/invalidcastexception-of-a-activator-createinstance-object-during-an-installation)